# Not able to send shipping address using PayPal android SDK with single Payment

Tags: android, paypal

I am using  PayPal Android SDK for Single Payment. When user checkout via "Pay with card", in this case, once payment is done in sandbox, in merchant account ,it shows below things in transaction detail page.(i.e. in https://www.sandbox.paypal.com)

---

Payment Status: Completed

-Seller Protection
Not Eligible

**We have no shipping address on file.**

Name:(The sender of this payment is Unregistered)
Email: No email address included

Payment Type:Website Payments Pro API Solution

AVS:

CSC:

I have added addAppProvidedShippingAddress method in code. But shipping address and name is not coming.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to pass through a shipping address for a direct credit card payment is not currently implemented in the REST APIs.  Since the mSDK runs on the REST APIs, there's not going to be an address tied to the transaction details in your account. That particular feature is only supported for PayPal payments.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your quick reply.
Can you please guide me on this. I am not even getting Name of buyer also. Is there any features in Mobile SDK for this?
(For e.g.

"Name: 
 (The sender of this payment is Unregistered)
Email: 
No email address included").

Apart from Mobile SDK, what are the other alternatives, in which i can implement Checkout via Paypal and Direct credit card within my mobile app in Android and iOS.

And i can send Shipping details and Buyer details in Direct credit card payment.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this time, that information isn't assigned for cc payments with mSDK.  As for alternatives, there's Mobile Express Checkout, however that's not a native solution.  More info on that can be found here:  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-express-checkout/